# How to create sliding menu like IBM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I am looking for a IBM like sliding menu for a project.I find this a best way when we have menu items that may spread across different categories.
Any css or javascript or jquery menu samples or snippets will be helpful.
Thanks
John

Comment: got a link to what you're looking for?

Comment: if you know where such a menu exists, you already have it's source code.

Comment: @chovy could you send me the link please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u try to make it ? maybe like [this](http://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-multilevel-menu-with-transition-and-animation/) or search on this [blog](http://www.treeshoots.com/)
If u know about css and jquery i think that will easy to make it because u have the basic maybe u must learn some trick to make it 99% same,cheers :))